# jquery doesn't get loaded, if i don't reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works only if I reload/refresh page, otherwise it doesn't work, I susspect issue is, because I use Jquery + normal javascript.

I have form and there is input which uses autocomplete, but while you go trough form next, it doesn't work.

The point is that input with #SchoolName isn't on first page is on 2nd page (after showcart(); function is trigered)...

Anyone have any ideas why my jquery code doesn't load properly?

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function autocomplete() {
        $("#SchoolName").autocomplete("ajaxFuncs.php", {
            cacheLength:1,
            mustMatch:1,
            extraParams: {getSchoolName:1}
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){
        setTimeout("autocomplete()", 500);
    });

    function showVal(str) {
        if (str == "") {   
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "* Please type in School Name.";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) { // break this into 2 statements so you can handle HTTP errors
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                } else {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "AJAX Error (HTTP "+xmlhttp.status+")";
                }
            }
        }; // functions declared in this way should be followed by a semi colon, since the function declaration is actually a statement.

        // encodeURIComponent() does all the escaping work for you - it is roughly analogous to PHP's urlencode()
        // xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxFuncs2.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);

        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxFuncs2.php?q="+encodeURIComponent(str),true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>



<script>
    function ajax(doc)
    {
        doc = null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            try {
                doc = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch(e) {
                if(SBDebug) 
                    alert("Ajax interface creation failure 1");
            }
        }
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            try {
                doc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e) {
                try {
                    doc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e) {
                    if(SBDebug)
                        alert("Ajax interface creation failure 2");
                }
            }
        }
        return doc;
    }



    function postIt(params) {
        var doc;
        // alert("postIt: " + params);  

        if(params == "")
            params = "nada=0";

        doc = ajax(doc);

        if (doc) {
            var url = window.location.href;
            url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + "clientCartPost.php";

            // alert(url);
            doc.open("POST", url, false);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            doc.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            doc.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            doc.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

            document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
            doc.send(params);
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";

            if(doc.responseText == "timeout") {
                alert("Timed out");
                document.location = "index.php";
            }
            return doc.responseText;
        }
        return "Connection Failed";
    }





    function saveCC() {
        var doc;
        doc = ajax(doc);

        if(params == "")
        params = "nada=0";

        if (doc) {
            var params = "";
            var eVisi = document.getElementById("visiCard");
            var eCard = document.getElementById("x_card_num");

            if(eVisi.value.indexOf("*") < 0)
                eCard.value = eVisi.value;

            for(i=0; i<document.CC.elements.length; i++) {
                if(document.CC.elements[i].name == "visiCard")
                    continue;

                params += getElemValue(document.CC.elements[i]) + "&";
            }

            doc.open("POST", "https://dot.precisehire.com/clientCartStoreCard.php", false);

            //Send the proper header information along with the request
            doc.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            doc.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
            doc.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

            document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
            doc.send(params);
            document.body.style.cursor = "default";

            // alert(doc.responseText);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }



    function getElemValue(item)

    {

    // alert("Getting: " + itemBase + itemID);

    // alert(itemBase + "" + itemID);

        if(item.type == "radio" || item.type == "checkbox")

        {

            if(!item.checked)

                return "";

        }

        if(item.type == "select-one")

        {

            value = item.options[item.selectedIndex].value;

        }

        else

            value = item.value;

        return item.name + "=" + escape(value) + "&";

    }



    function    makePie()

    {

        var contents = postIt("command=getProgress");



        document.getElementById("step2").className = "bx2";

        document.getElementById("step3").className = "bx2";

        document.getElementById("step4").className = "bx2";

        if(contents > 0)

            document.getElementById("step2").className = "bx1";

        if(contents > 1)

            document.getElementById("step3").className = "bx1";

        if(contents > 2)

            document.getElementById("step4").className = "bx1";

    }



    var gbColor;



    function    RedIn(start)

    {

        var id;



        if(start)

            gbColor = 0;

        gbColor += 32;

        if(gbColor > 255)

            gbColor = 255;

        id = 0;

        var obj = document.getElementById("red" + id);

        while(obj != undefined)

        {

            obj.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255,' + gbColor + ',' + gbColor + ')'; 

            id++;

            obj = document.getElementById("red" + id);

        }

        if(gbColor < 255 && id > 0)

            setTimeout("RedIn(0)", 100);

    }



    function    showCart(next)

    {

        var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");

        var params = "";



        for(i=0; i<document.clientCart.elements.length; i++)

        {

            param = getElemValue(document.clientCart.elements[i]);

            if(param != "")

                params += param + "&";

        }

        if(next)

            params += "Next=1";

    // alert(params);

        ca.innerHTML = postIt(params);



        makePie();

    //  RedIn(1);

    }



    function    tabIfComplete(formField, maxSize, nextField, e)

    {

        if(window.event) // IE

        {

            keynum = e.keyCode;

        }

        else if(e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera

        {

            keynum = e.which;

        }

        if(keynum < 48)

            return;

        if(formField.value.length >= maxSize)

        {

            var nf = document.getElementById(nextField);



            if(nf)

                nf.focus();

        }

    }



    function    sendCommand(command)

    {

        var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");

        var params = "command=" + command;

        var submitOrder = command.indexOf('submitOrder') >= 0;

    // alert(command);

        if(submitOrder)

        {

            if(document.getElementById("RESULT").checked)

            {

                params += "&postSettlement=result";

    /*

                n = postIt(params);

                alert(nOID);

                if(nOID > 0)

                    document.location="orderreview.php?id=" + nOID;

                return;

    */

            }

            else if(document.getElementById("REPORT").checked)

            {

                params += "&postSettlement=report";

            }

            else if(document.getElementById("DUPEORDER").checked)

            {

                params += "&postSettlement=dupeorder";

            }

            postIt(params);

            document.location="cart.php";

            return;

        }

        else if(command.indexOf('priorSearches') >= 0)

        {

            document.location="orderreview.php?ssnlist=1";

        }

        else if(command.indexOf('addState') >= 0)

        {

            for(i=0; i<document.clientCart.elements.length; i++)

            {

                if(document.clientCart.elements[i].name != "Next")

                    params += "&" + getElemValue(document.clientCart.elements[i]);

            }

        }

        ca.innerHTML = postIt(params);

        makePie();

    }



    function    doReset()

    {

        var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");



        ca.innerHTML = "";

        ca.innerHTML = postIt("reset=1");

        makePie();

    }



    function    dupeOrder()

    {

        var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");



        ca.innerHTML = "";

        ca.innerHTML = postIt("dupeOrder=1");

        makePie();

    }



    function    resetCart()

    {

        if(confirm("Empty current cart and start over? Are you Sure?"))

            doReset();

    }



    function    saveCart()

    {

        var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");

        var params = "";



        for(i=0; i<document.clientCart.elements.length; i++)

        {

            params += getElemValue(document.clientCart.elements[i]) + "&";

        }

        params += "saveExit=1";

        ca.innerHTML = postIt(params);

        makePie();

        RedIn(1);

    }



    function    deleteOrderItem(command)

    {

        if(!confirm("Delete this search? Are you Sure?"))

            return;



        var ca = document.getElementById("cartArea");

        var params = "command=" + command;



        ca.innerHTML = postIt(params);

        makePie();

    }



    // alert("Reloaded");



    setTimeout("showCart();", 100);

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using XMLHttpRequest when you already have jQuery?

Comment: And where in all that wall of JS are you actually loading jquery?

Comment: Please remove all non-relevant pieces of code

Comment: @Viruzzo - Maybe an explanation to why he shouldn't be using XMLHttpRequest if he already has jQuery? It would help me out to know why and maybe him as well.

Comment: @Samjus -- that should be asked in a separate question, if it hasn't already.

Comment: @Viruzzo I would like to know what can I use instead of XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: @Samjus at the very least so he could do the same stuff in many less lines of code.

Comment: @Drazek use jQuery's Ajax API: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: @Matt Fenwick - I felt like I needed to ask it because it was relevant to this question because it was brought up in the comments.

Comment: This code is such a mess that it's difficult to sort through it all, but it looks like you are calling some of your code using timeouts before the DOM might be ready and thus the code would fail until the page comes from the browser cache and thus loads faster.  ALL code that access the page MUST be run AFTER the page is loaded.  Since you have jQuery, the easiest way to do that is to put code like `showCart()` inside a `$(document).ready()` block.

Comment: Meh I ended up removing real code when I attempted to edit. rolled back.. someone else can give it a shot.

Comment: Instead of `setTimeout("autocomplete()", 500);`, you should use `setTimeout(autocomplete, 500);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the last line:

```
setTimeout("showCart();", 100);
```

...into the $.ready-function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout("autocomplete()", 500);
});
```

Otherwise it may happen that showCart() gets called before the elements you access in showCart() are known.

Comment: This is my guess too (see my comment to the OP that says the same thing), though it's purely a guess and there may be others.

Comment: @jfriend00 When I tryed that. My console start to say => showVal is not defined

Comment: @Drazek.  Then you may have done something the wrong way.  Not much we can do without seeing exactly what you did.

Comment: I did this:
`$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout("autocomplete()", 500);
    setTimeout("showCart()", 100);
});`

Answer (score 1):

First: Combining jQuery + regular javascript is not a problem -- jquery is made of regular javascript.

Secondly, when you're passing a method into your callback param anything, you can usually just write the name of the method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(autocomplete, 500);
});
```

Third, the issue of using XMLHttpRequest while also using jquery. Jquery has a version of the XHR that is even more cross browser compliant than that is, you should use it:

```
$.ajax()
```

Finally, please add an include to the actual jquery file at the beginning of your code..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to say, while formatting your code its really pain to do.

I have seen some of issue right now:-

1. `function autocomplete() {` first this function has improver closing `};` with semi-colon
2. Below is the repeatitive code:-

> ```
>   //Send the proper header information along with the request
> doc.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
> doc.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
> doc.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
> document.body.style.cursor = "wait";
> doc.send(params);
> document.body.style.cursor = "default";</li>
> ```
>
> This you can make into a single function call by passing proper parameters.

3.If you are using JQuery then `XMLHttpRequest` is not required
4.Yet to update...

Answer (score 1):

Open up a javascript console (Ctrl-Shift-J) in Firefox/Chrome and look in the menu bar for other browsers and see what errors show up